# Comparing 2 Lists of type int at equal index

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops

I have 2 List to keep track of x and y coordinates on a grid.

Im looping through the height and then width and then using an if check to see if the w and h values are in the lists at the same index.

Heres what I got but its not working quite right.

```
for (int h = yMin; h <= yMax; h++)
{
  for (int w = xMin; w <= xMax; w++)
  {
    if (x[w] == (w) && y[h] == (h)) 
    {
       //do some code
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using the .Contains method on the lists but that doesnt compare them at the same index... I dont care what index they are at in the lists, as long as they are at the same index in both.

```
if (x.Contains(w) && y.Contains(h))
```

Im looking for some way to test what index they were found at inside of the list. The List could contain more than 1 of the same numbers as well.

```
if (x.Contains(w) && y.Contains(h))
{
    if (x.FoundIndex(w). == y.FoundIndex(h))
    {
        // this would be awesome if it worked!!!!
    }
}
```

Just a note on the variables.. yMin and xMin start at 0 and the for loops are inside of a do while loop which will increase them by 1 each iteration. The yMax and xMax are the size of the square we are looking at inside of the grid.

Maybe there is a better way that I just dont know about.. I tried to find a Coordinate datatype/object but was unsuccessful.

The only way I could think of doing it is looping thru the x list and for each index comparing it to the y list at the same index. Just seems like there should be a cleaner way of doing this.

Please help!

EDIT 1:
After thinking about what I was trying to accomplish, I was able to wrap my head around it and come up with this... And this how my code is in my program just for you @DJ KRAZE

```
for (int intCnt = 0; intCnt < lstXCoord.Count(); intCnt++)
{
    if (lstXCoord[intCnt] == intWidth)
    {
        if (lstYCoord[intCnt] == intHeight)
        {
            // do my code..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy I would suggest that if you are using a List<T> that you do not use variable names like x, h, w, ...etc this makes your code terribly hard to read.. I hope that the rest of your coding is not that sloppy.

Comment: I just used that for example. My real code uses hungarian notation. lst, int, str, etc.. ;)

Comment: Thanks for trying to providing code that follow default C# guidelines. It is good idea to not put hungarian notation is public sample. To make it really nice - use meaningful names for index variables and coordinate lists (as DJ suggested).

Comment: well perhaps you should have posted the example using the real notation.. makes others think that your variables are Integers and not List<T>

Comment: Oh my bad.. Just thought it would be helpful to those looking to answer if i put in there that my problem is/was using C# code. Will keep that in mind for the future, and thank you! I have used this site many times, but was almost always able to find my answer without posting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
if (x.IndexOf(w) == y.IndexOf(h))
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I get where your going with that, but like I said, I dont care, or necessarily know what index it could be at. The lists could have 2 values each, up to 1,000 values. I want the values at a given index of 2 separate lists to match my 'w' and 'h' to know if the coordinate pair im looking at exists inside of the area im testing.